# Apache returns 503 error accesing address with mod_jk configured

Tags: tomcat, apache-2.4, mod-jk

I have a Tomcat server listening at 10881 AJP port. I confirmed it by netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10881           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2297/java
```

This is the configuration of Tomcat server.xml file:

```
<Connector port="10881" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="portal">
```

This is worker.properties file:

```
worker.list=portal,jkstatus


#liferay portal
worker.portal.type=ajp13
worker.portal.host=localhost
worker.portal.port=10881

#jk status
worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

And this is the VirtualHost config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/portal
        ServerName portal.local
        ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/portal.local-error-log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 10M"
        CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/portal.local-access-log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 10M" combined

        #JkMount features
        JkMount /* portal

        <Directory />
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And when I try to enter to portal.local it returns a 503 error code. I took a look to the mod_jk.log file and this is its content:

```
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1170): Attempting to map URI '/' from 1 maps
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map context URI '/*=portal' source 'JkMount'
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (997): Found a wildchar match '/*=portal'
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2639): Into handler jakarta-servlet worker=portal r->proxyreq=0
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (115): found a worker portal
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] wc_maintain::jk_worker.c (338): Maintaining worker portal
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (292): Found worker type 'ajp13'
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] init_ws_service::mod_jk.c (1108): Service protocol=HTTP/1.1 method=GET ssl=false host=(null) addr=172.22.14.137 name=portal.local port=80 auth=(null) user=(null) laddr=172.22.14.68 raddr=172.22.14.137 uaddr=172.22.14.137 uri=/
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3213): acquired connection pool slot=0 after 0 retries
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_marshal_into_msgb::jk_ajp_common.c (650): ajp marshaling done
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2500): processing portal with 2 retries
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1657): (portal) all endpoints are disconnected.
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (616): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (740): trying to connect socket 24 to ::1:10881
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (758): connect to ::1:10881 failed (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1019): Failed opening socket to (::1:10881) (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1663): (portal) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (portal) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2522): retry 1, sleeping for 100 ms before retrying
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1657): (portal) all endpoints are disconnected.
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (616): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (740): trying to connect socket 24 to ::1:10881
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (758): connect to ::1:10881 failed (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1019): Failed opening socket to (::1:10881) (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1663): (portal) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (portal) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2693): (portal) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_reset_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (810): (portal) resetting endpoint with socket -1 (socket shutdown)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_done::jk_ajp_common.c (3144): recycling connection pool for worker portal and socket -1
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2766:140245744498752] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2806): Service error=-3 for worker=portal
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2798:140245744498752] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (634): Attached shared memory /var/log/httpd/jk-runtime-status.2507 [7] size=1024 workers=0 free=0 addr=0x7f8d81c90000
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2798:140245744498752] [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (430): Duplicated shared memory lock /var/log/httpd/jk-runtime-status.2507.lock
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:34 2015] [2798:140245744498752] [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3266): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.40
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1170): Attempting to map URI '/favicon.ico' from 1 maps
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map context URI '/*=portal' source 'JkMount'
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (997): Found a wildchar match '/*=portal'
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2639): Into handler jakarta-servlet worker=portal r->proxyreq=0
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (115): found a worker portal
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] wc_maintain::jk_worker.c (338): Maintaining worker portal
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (292): Found worker type 'ajp13'
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] init_ws_service::mod_jk.c (1108): Service protocol=HTTP/1.1 method=GET ssl=false host=(null) addr=172.22.14.137 name=portal.local port=80 auth=(null) user=(null) laddr=172.22.14.68 raddr=172.22.14.137 uaddr=172.22.14.137 uri=/favicon.ico
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3213): acquired connection pool slot=0 after 0 retries
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_marshal_into_msgb::jk_ajp_common.c (650): ajp marshaling done
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2500): processing portal with 2 retries
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1657): (portal) all endpoints are disconnected.
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (616): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (740): trying to connect socket 24 to ::1:10881
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (758): connect to ::1:10881 failed (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1019): Failed opening socket to (::1:10881) (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1663): (portal) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (portal) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2522): retry 1, sleeping for 100 ms before retrying
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1657): (portal) all endpoints are disconnected.
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (616): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (740): trying to connect socket 24 to ::1:10881
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (758): connect to ::1:10881 failed (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1019): Failed opening socket to (::1:10881) (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1663): (portal) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (portal) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2693): (portal) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_reset_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (810): (portal) resetting endpoint with socket -1 (socket shutdown)
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [debug] ajp_done::jk_ajp_common.c (3144): recycling connection pool for worker portal and socket -1
[Thu Mar 05 14:03:37 2015] [2763:140245744498752] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2806): Service error=-3 for worker=portal
```

I can see an 111 error that says port is probably not listening but as I wrote it does. I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the mod_jk version. I compiled it from the latest version of Tomcat Connectors (1.2.40). Then I tried to compile it with a lower version of T. C. (1.2.35) and it worked.